# Js Array.prototype.map() happens to be mutable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, immutability, mutable

Why would the map method mutate the original array when its [initial purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is to create a new array ?

I have an array of object which I pass to a pure function which in turn maps the given array and return a new one. Then I notice that the original array was also changed.. I understand the concept that Object in Js are passed by reference and all but still cant quite grab why would the implementation of `map` would mutate the original array, kinda beats the purpose IMO.

```
var initialArray = [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three'} ];

function doSomething(array) {

  // lodash
  // return _.map(array, (item) => _.assign(item, {isSelected: true}));  

  // vanilla
  return array.map(function(item) {
    item['isSelected'] = true;
    return item
  });

}

var changedArray = doSomething(initialArray);

console.log('initialArray', initialArray); // [{ name: 'one', isSelected: true }, ...]
console.log('changedArray', changedArray); // [{ name: 'one', isSelected: true }, ...]
console.log(initialArray === changedArray); // false
```

First Id like to understand why this happens ?

Second Id like to understand how would one map an array without changing the original one ? (ie. doing `._cloneDeep` each time before `map` feels wrong)

Thanks in advance !

### Edit

Ok so from what I understand this is how things just are. I think I might have had higher expectation for some reason, but it is explainable in Js so at least there is some consistency in place.

The most elegant solution I can think of for creating a new array with new members is

```
return _.map(array, (item) => _.assign({}, ...item, {isSelected: true}));
```

Comment: A comment about the last line: `console.log( initialArray...`. This almost never works if you have to compare arrays (or for that matter, Objects) in JavaScript. Have a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76wyLxj5/

Comment: I can't post it as an answer as it'll be off-topic, but here is a great answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.map` will create a new array, but the objects inside the array is still referenced.

so when you make changes in the `object item` inside .map function, it is referencing the original object in the input array.

one way to fix it is to clone the each object , before you modify it

```
var initialArray = [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three'} ];

function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

function doSomething(array) {

  // lodash
  // return _.map(array, (item) => _.assign(item, {isSelected: true}));  

  // vanilla
  return array.map(function(item) {
    var copy = clone(item);
    copy['isSelected'] = true;
    return copy;
  });

}

var changedArray = doSomething(initialArray);

console.log('initialArray', initialArray); // [{ name: 'one'}, ...]
console.log('changedArray', changedArray); // [{ name: 'one', isSelected: true }, ...]
console.log(initialArray === changedArray); // false
```

Credit : clone function is copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: You can use array.slice() instead of that clone function, but yeah.

Comment: Or use any of the options [here](https://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-json-stringify-json-parse/34) (see what best fits your need performance wise)

Comment: One could also make a copy of the original property by using the `Object.assign({}, propertyOrTheWholeObjectToBeCopied)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just solve for OP's example then you can spread the `item` object into a new object returned from `Array.map()`.

```js
var initialArray = [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three'} ];

function doSomething(array) {

  // lodash
  // return _.map(array, (item) => _.assign(item, {isSelected: true}));  

  // vanilla
  return array.map(function(item) {
    return {
      ...item,
      isSelected: true
    }
  });

}

var changedArray = doSomething(initialArray);

console.log('initialArray', initialArray); // initialArray [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three' } ] 
console.log('changedArray', changedArray); // changedArray [ { name: 'one', isSelected: true }, { name: 'two', isSelected: true }, { name: 'three', isSelected: true } ] 
console.log(initialArray === changedArray); // false
```

Note: This solution wouldn't allow you to dereference any objects nested beyond level one without also using the spread operator.

More information on the `spread` operator can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

Answer (score 2):

your modifying the object that get's passed by reference to the map function, not the array that get's mapped. Both the `changedArray` and the `initialArray` contain the same object.

```js
var initialArray = [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three'} ];
var initialArray2 = [ { name: 'one' }, { name: 'two' }, { name: 'three'} ];

function doSomething(array) {
  // vanilla
  return array.map(function(item) {
    item['isSelected'] = true;
    return item
  });

}

function doSomethingElse(array){
  return array.map(function( item ){
    // return a new object don't change the initial one
    return { name: item.name, isSelected: true };
  });
}

var changedArray = doSomething(initialArray),
    differentObjectsInArray = doSomethingElse( initialArray2 );

console.assert( initialArray !== changedArray, 'both arrays are different' );
console.assert( initialArray[0] !== changedArray[0], 'both arrays are referencing different objects' );
console.assert( initialArray2[0] !== differentObjectsInArray[0], 'both arrays are referencing different objects' );
console.log('initialArray', initialArray );
console.log('initialArray2', initialArray2 );
console.log('differentObjectsInArray', differentObjectsInArray );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var targetArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(souceArray));
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.